# django tastypie returning 401 always for POST method and works well for GET

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

Here is my code

```
     class termTypeResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:
           queryset = TermType.objects.all()
           resource_name = 'gettermtypes'
           allowed_methods = ['get','post']
```

Whenever I do curl for the api like below

```
 curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data {"termtype":"LONG"}' --apiURL--
```

it is returning (Note: I dont want to add authentication or authorization for api POST)

```
HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Date: Fri, 17 Oct 2014 12:05:49 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: So where are yours authorization header?

Comment: @coldmind I have removed authorization from api since i dont need that,even then it is returning 401.

Answer (score 1):

From tastypie tutorial:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#hooking-up-the-resource-s

> However, if you try sending a POST/PUT/DELETE to the resource, you
>   find yourself getting “401 Unauthorized” errors. For safety, Tastypie
>   ships with the authorization class (“what are you allowed to do”) set
>   to ReadOnlyAuthorization. This makes it safe to expose on the web, but
>   prevents us from doing POST/PUT/DELETE. Let’s enable those:

```
authorization = Authorization()
```

But you specified this as `Authorization =`, it's wrong.
And, how it is mentioned in tutorial, POST and etc. without authentication is insecure.